# Replacing portion of rotted sill plate and studs

Tags: repair, framing, joists, sill

A section of my home has sustained water damage from an improperly installed platform deck.  The damaged section includes about 1' portion of a few studs around a window and a 3' section of the sill plate, which rests on the concrete foundation.  The entire wall is about 4' high and runs parallel with the floor joists (house is a back split).  My intention is to replace the section of sill plate and sister/replace the damaged studs, how concerned should I be about temporarily supporting the rim joist above?  Again, this wall runs parallel with the floor joists above, which bear on the adjacent exterior wall and an interior carrying beam with a point load further down this wall.  The rim joist above is basically a continuous header, would it even sag at all if a 3' section of studs were removed?  My intention is to complete all this work from the outside.

[image: Affected cross section]

My thought for temporary support.  Remove the window and fill it with cripples to the foundation on the unaffected sill plate.  Add 1-2 full length studs on the unaffected area to close the gap which would be roughly 3'.

[image: Temporary support option]

My other thought was to bolt some blocks or a temporary 2x8 header to the unaffected studs which would stick out past the foundation and allow me to wedge temporary supports that will rest on concrete blocks on the ground:

[image: Temporary support option]

I don't know if I'm overthinking this or if it will be an issue at all but I can't think of any other way to support it - it's not like I can build a temporary wall to support it, but then again, would I even have to?

Also, how important is it to bolt this section of sill back down?  Can I just use tapcons if I don't land on a preexisting bolt?  Could I also replace it in pieces?  Say so I didn't have to remove so much at once?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Confirm that the 2x8 is sitting on the top plate, not just outside.  If you do have that odd 2x8 as a header and a single story(roof sits above the header), then I think you have an easy job of just remove and replace.

Comment: It's just the outer most joist sitting on the top plate.  There is a second floor, but again this wall runs parallel with the joists.  This outer most joist has full bearing on a beam and the corner, with all the studs in between.  I can't see a huge problem removing a couple of the studs as it is still supported by everything else and is essentially a header.  Obviously if the ends of each joist were landing on this wall it would be a different story.

Answer (score 2):

I like your idea for temporary support. My suggestions would be to rent a few floor jacks from your home store and use them instead of the double studs and the cripples. It will be easier to adjust the support and get proper fitting for your studs, king and jack studs and bottom cripple. I'd replace the sill in one piece and use the Tapcons. No reason messing around doing it in pieces.

Comment: Do you think I can safely remove a 3' section if I add the additional support?  There is a second floor above (exterior wall) and all the joists run parallel with this wall.  To me, removing a 3' section would have the rim joist act like a header, no different than a door or window.

Comment: For the short period of time you're talking about, I wouldn't hesitate to do it myself.